# How to create custom nav bar to support safeareaview in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, safeareaview

I'm using this for creating navbar but in iPhoneX it getting break due to safe area view layout

```
 navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
    cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(onTapCancel:)];
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelBtn;
    [navbar setItems:@[navItem]];
```

[image]

How can we do this in Objective-C to support iPhoneX?

Answer (score 0):

here is the workaround to fix navigation bar

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    int start = self.view.safeAreaInsets.top;
       UINavigationBar * navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, start, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 50)];
         navbar.prefersLargeTitles = YES;

       UINavigationItem*  navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];

         [navbar setItems:@[navItem]];

         [self.view addSubview:navbar];

}
```